# Как достать html из ePub?

Tags: php, format, epub

Всем привет.

Хочу достать html от разных книг в ePub формате. Есть ли для этого качественные инструменты, которые выдирают стандартизированный html или их надо писать самостоятельно?

Например: я залил свои книги ePub на bookmate, он мне предоставил качественный html из них.  При этом, использую те-же книги в онлайн-конверторе вышла абракадабра.

Спасибо!

Comment: Можно просто распаковать через 7-zip, там будут и страницы с версткой и стили и все фото!

Comment: [sigil](https://sigil-ebook.com/)

Comment: Спасибо. Но вижу, что все равно разные html выходит, в букмейте и через 7-zip. Видимо у них своя программа какая-то стоит